# Eventlistener in javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, addeventlistener

I have a code that adds a check-all toggle to each of my buttons that are named "CheckAll"
I recently faced a problem where from IE browsers, the buttons were not working, and I found out addEventListener does not work in IE, and you have to use attachEvent, however some people are saying this can have consequences as well, and they're recommending jQuery. So can somebody demonstrate a jQuery version of my javaScript?
Here's the code

```
function script1(){
var el = document.getElementsByName('CheckAll');  
el1 = el[0];  
el2 = el[1];
el3 = el[2];
el4 = el[3];
el5 = el[4];
el6 = el[5];
el7 = el[6];



el1.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(0,8)}, false);
el2.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(8,16)}, false);
el3.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(16,26)}, false);
el4.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(26,34)}, false);
el5.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(34,44)}, false);
el6.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(44,52)}, false);
el7.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(52,60)}, false);


}
```

and here is a jfiddle
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHXDx/4/)

Comment: `el1.addEventListener('click', function(){selectAll(0,8)}, false);` --> `$(el1).on('click', function(){selectAll(0,8)});` see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: SO is not a code translation service. Please read the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, there is one simple function to bind events: `.on`. You can select elements using the `$` function using CSS notation: http://jsfiddle.net/VHXDx/11/. This would be all that's needed, without a `selectAll` function:

```
// run when elements are available
$(function() {
    // select the `CheckAll` buttons and run a function for each one
    $("input[name='CheckAll']").each(function(i) {  // `i` is a counter
        // bind event
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            // select `AG[]` elements in the current row and toggle their checked property
            $(this).closest("tr").find("[name='AG[]']").prop("checked", function(j, current) {
                return !current;
            });
        });
    });
}​);​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function script1(){
    var el = $('[name="CheckAll"]');
    el.on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('td').siblings().find('input[name="AG[]"]').each(function(i,e) {
            e.checked = !e.checked;
        });
    });
}
```

​
[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VHXDx/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `attachEvent`? You can easily build a [simple crossbrowser `addEvent` function](http://quirksmode.org/js/eventSimple.html) without using jQuery.

```
var add = document.addEventListener ? function(el, type, fn) {
    el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
} : function(el, type, fn) {
    el.attachEvent("on"+type, fn.bind(el), false);
};

function script1(){
    var els = document.getElementsByName('CheckAll');
    var a = 1, b = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
        a *= -1;
        add(els[i], 'click', selectAll.bind(null, b, b+= 9+a));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to use `.bind` but not assume `.addEventListener`.

Comment: I think it is easier shimmable than `addEventListener`. Also, without `bind` the code would have become a horrible closure mess :-)